# If closed sets $A,B\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ are non-homeomorphic, can $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus A$ and $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus B$ be homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

I have a question. Could you please help me to solve this problem?

Is it possible that $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus A$ and $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus B$ are homeomorphic, when $A$ and $B$ are non-homeomorphic closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: fun fact: in $X= \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ we can take any 2 sigma-compact sets $A$ and $B$ and $X \setminus A$ will be homeomorphic to $X \setminus B$. So there we have plenty of such examples...

Answer (score 7):

$A= \{(0,0)\}$, $B=B[0,1] $ i.e closed unit ball is an example of this.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds wrong. Maybe I can't see the picture, but if you take $A={0}$ and $B={0,1}$, then the first space will have two connected components and the second three.

Comment: No, what you say is true for $\mathbb{R}$, not for $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Yes, I stand corrected. I should have read the question better :)

Comment: But then again, take A to be the $y$ axis and take B to be the $y$-axis and the $x$-axis, won't it work the same way?